# Ckeditor Default Font size, Color

Tags: css, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using CKEditor. When I paste data, CKEditor adds a `font` element with `color` and `size` attributes. I want to override these and keep `font-size: 11px` and `font-color: #000000`.

```html
This is Test Data to check Font color and Size
Added Font size +1

<font color="#1f497d" face="Calibri" size="3">
<font color="#000000"  size="11">
```

Needs to override

```
<font color="#000000"  size="11">
```

Answer (score 0):

To set your default Font size, you need to customize the config of CKEditor,
To do so, please check the link : [CKEdior Default font, font-size config](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-font_style)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your contents.css

```
body
{/* Font */
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;/* Text color */
color: #00649d;/* Remove the background color to make it transparent */
background-color: #fff;
}
```